# Android App opening different activity when it is installed

Tags: android, android-activity, launcher, bluestacks

`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ReservedTableActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".WaitingListActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ReservationActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".InvoiceViewActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ForReservedUserActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ToInvoiceActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MenuActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PushActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CustomPrintActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_custom_print"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.myapp.rms.CUSTOM_INTENT">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
</application>
```

`In My android app when i am launching my app from android studio to bluestack it is working fine as it is launching the activity which i set as launcher but the problem is when i am closing app and reopening by clicking the icon(Not from android studio), this is launching another activity.  as in my menifest i have set MainActivity as launcher but this is opening PushActivity when i am reopening app.Actually I set PushActivity as launcher once but now i have set MainActivity as launcher.but this is not launching MainActivity

Comment: post your manifest

Comment: Actually it happens when we change launcher from one activity to another activity and after that if we want to make it as before ,it shows this problem. any solution??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i was using bluestack. Not sure what the problem is but i solved it by uninstalling the app in bluestack and then installing it again from android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Use this  tag in your launcher activity declaration.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```